# Search for a string/pattern in selected text in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to decrypt the selected text if the string "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----" occurs in the selected text.
I have the following code but it doesn't show up anything.

```
#!/bin/bash
xsel > pgp.txt
if [grep -e "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----" pgp.txt]
then
gnome-terminal --command "gpg -d -o decrypted.txt pgp.txt"
gedit decrypted.txt
fi
```

When I run it on terminal after selecting a text it says

```
line 3: [grep: command not found
```

I'm new to bash scripting.Any help would be appreciated..
Thank you

Comment: I think serverfault will be a better place to ask these kind of questions. stackoverflow.com is for programming, not linux scripting. For linux like server stuff, go to serverfault.com

Comment: @algorian, the question is elementary but about the shell as a programming language, I don't see why it would be less acceptable than a similar one with a lisp dialect.

Comment: You should avoid temporary files. If they cannot be avoided, they should be removed when you're done with them. Concretely, try `if xsel | grep -q -e 'stuff'; then` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It searches an executable called `[grep` as `if` argument. `if` executes its then or else branch depending if its argument execute successfully or not.  Yes, `[` is a command (synonym for `test` btw). You probably want

```
if grep -q -e "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----" pgp.txt
then
```

(added `-q` so `grep` doesn't output anything.)

Comment: When I use "if grep -qe -e "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----" pgp.txt
then"
 the terminal says "grep: unrecognized option '-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information."

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing some elements here :

- Spaces : there one after the opening '[' and another before the closing ']'
- Backquotes : Because you need to test the result of the executed grep command
- a ';' after the closing ']'

Here is a rewritten version :

```
if [ `grep -e "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----" pgp.txt` ]; then
  gnome-terminal --command "gpg -d -o decrypted.txt pgp.txt"
  gedit decrypted.txt
fi
```

Comment: Since the search string is not a pattern here, but a fixed string, you could also use fgrep here:

    if [ $(fgrep -e "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----" pgp.txt) ]

Note that I used $( .. ) above for command substitution but backquotes (``) are perfectly valid here as well, though they can not be nested (not needed here).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you two variants. Both are equal

```
if $(grep -q -- "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----" pgp.txt);
then
```

OR

```
if $(grep -qe "-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----" pgp.txt);
then
```